# Using select options in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am creating a program in which I have three select filed; main categories, subcategories, and finalCategories respectively. So what i want is when i choose any option from main categories should display the subcategories of the related selected category in the subcategories field. And also when i choose any option from subcategories field finalCategories of the related subcategory should be displayed in the finalcategory field.

example;

```
                <select id="mainCategories">
                    <option>Fashion</option>
                    <option>Electronics</option>
                    <option>Another Thing</option>
                </select>
```

Subcategories of Fashions are like

1. Mens fashion
2. Womens fashion
3. Kids fashion

And finalCategories of Mens fashion are like;

1. Mens Trousers
2. Mens Suit
3. Mens shoes
4. Vests

So that is the structure for all categories

see the image below

[this is how the select fields looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKctV.jpg)

Comment: Great, did you have a question?

Comment: So, What you actually want?

Comment: Read my question again. what i want is to use the data from the first select field to retrieve data in another select field and so on

Comment: So where is the data coming from? I mean if you select a category I guess the sub category data need to be loaded from the DB, so you shoudl use AJAX to send a request to a PHP script and return the data to fill teh second select box.. if you don't have that many sub categories you could preload all the data beforehand, so you won't need AJAX.

Comment: The data are retrieved from the DB. Can you help me on how to use AJAX to send a request to a PHP script? @xander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using jQuery to construct new data to the other select. Here's the idea:

1. Loop all data in main category
2. Leave the other select sub-categories empty but keep the id of each select's
3. Bind an event on change for each select's

quick example:

```js
// I assume you already have jQuery

$(function(){
  $('select#mainCat').on('change', function(){
    // AJAX Request here to get the subcategory by main category.
    var mainCatId = $(this).val();
    console.log(mainCatId);
    var url = 'http://www.example.com/get_subcat_by_maincat';
    // you can retrieve mainCatId by $_POST['mainCat'];
    var data = {
      mainCat: mainCatId
    };
    $.post(url, data, function(rtn){
      console.log(rtn);
      $('select#subCat').html(rtn);
    }, 'html');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mainCat" name="mainCat">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="subCat" name="subCat">
</select>
```

on the server side:

```
<?php
$optStr = '';
if($subCatData){
   foreach($subCatData as $value){
      $optStr .= '<option value=".$value->field_one.">".$value->field_two."</option>';
   }
}
print $optStr;
exit;
?>
```

do something similar to the other subcategories and be creative based on your needs.

Comment: This is a good starting point, but I suggest using a get-request (not that it matters much) and returning JSON encoded data from the PHP script, instead of HTML. You can easily create the `<option>` elements with jQuery on the client, so prefer to only send the "raw" data.

Comment: that is also correct, I actually haven't compared these two methods of getting and displaying the data and actually I am trying to give the thread starter a picture to use onChange event.

Comment: which part is not working for you and how would you get the data for the first main category and could you please include the server-side script?

Comment: the data for sub categories have to be retrieved from the database. so i want to use the option's value to retrieve the data

Comment: just run the script to get the values from the database, if you are confused on using jQuery, try the above method first. On the server side, loop the result and echo the result in an option value.